# Oracle SQL Query - Age

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have the following table in my Oracle Database:

```
create table FilmStar (
  filmStarID   char(25) not null,
  filmStarName char(50) not null,
  birthplace   char(50) not null,
  yearBorn     char(25) not null,
  yearDied     char(25),

  primary key (filmStarID)
);

insert into FilmStar values ('0001','Tim Robbins','California, United States','1958',null);

insert into FilmStar values ('0005','Marlon Brando','Nebraska, United States','1924','2004');
```

I need to complete the following query: List the unique numbers, names, and ages of all film stars who are deceased.

I believe that I need to

```
select * from FilmStar where yearDied is not null
```

but how to find out the age?

Comment: Why did you tag this MySQL if it's for Oracle?

Comment: Why are `yearBorn` and `yearDied` stored as strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to be explicit about type conversions:

```
select . . .,
       (cast(yearDied as int) - cast(yearBorn as int) ) as approximate_age
from FilmStart
where yearDied is not null;
```

Relying on implicit conversions can result in *very* hard to find errors.  Storing numbers as strings just exacerbates this problem.

Note:  in Oracle, one is inclined to use `to_number()` rather than `cast()` for this purpose.

Comment: to_date() would be better than to_number() in that case.

Comment: @ffarquet . . . Except the value appears to only contain the year.

Comment: It is more general with to_date(). Years could be encoded with 2 digits only for instance. to_date() would work in that case but to_number() not.